# WordPress Cron Job not importing products

Tags: plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic, wp-cron, cron, development-strategy

I think this issue is related to WordPres Cron System , because the function runs fine without cron but it doesn't work as expected when run via cron , please have a look : https://wordpress.org/support/topic/woocommerce-products-not-being-imported-via-wp-cron-job/

let me know if any details needed

Comment: StackExchange questions should have all relevant information. Linking out to external sources is not helpful. Please bring in and structure the information.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have added the details on the wordpress.org questions forum , but let me add it here as well